# Error al eliminar tuplas de una tabla mas una intermedia

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo 3 tablas, `NOTICIA`, `NOTICIA_FOTO` (tabla intermedia) y `FOTO`, y necesito eliminar filas de la tabla `FOTO`; y dado que dicha tabla está asociada a la tabla intermedia `NOTICIA_FOTO`, también eliminar filas de esa tabla. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es eliminar varias filas de una vez, utilizando el `Contains`, donde al `Contains` le paso una lista de ids de `FOTO` a eliminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<HttpPost>
Function EditarNoticia(form As FormCollection) As ActionResult

Dim noticiaSelec As NOTICIA = db.NOTICIA.Where(Function(x) x.IdNoticia = id_noticia).Single()

 noticiaSelec.TituloNoticia = form("TituloNoticia")
 noticiaSelec.DescripcionNoticia = form("DescripcionNoticia")
 noticiaSelec.FechaPublicacionNoticia = Date.Now


 Dim idsEliminar() As Integer =   Array.ConvertAll(form("ids_eliminar").Split(","), Function(x) Int32.Parse(x))
Dim idsEliminarList As List(Of Integer) = idsEliminar.ToList

Dim fotosEliminar = db.FOTO.Where(Function(x)    idsEliminarList.Contains(x.IdFoto))        
noticiaSelec.FOTO.Remove(fotosEliminar) ‘ Aquí es donde se cae
db.SaveChanges()
……
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Nombre del error: No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.FOTO]'
>   al tipo 'IMPCHLosCopihues_MVC.FOTO'.

Sé que algo tengo mal, y quizá la query `fotosEliminar` esté mal, pero me lanza el error en `noticiaSelec.FOTO.Remove(fotosEliminar)`. Si alguien sabe cómo solucionar este error, se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `noticiaSelec.FOTO` ? y el error es de compilación o ejecución?

Comment: La pregunta esta etiquetada como [tag:linq-to-sql] pero creo que estás usando Entity Framework verdad?

Comment: Si @CarlosMuñoz , está en lo correcto, uso Entity Framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es que al usar el `Where()` este devuelve una query cuando el `Remove()` necesita un único item.

Deberias usar `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
Dim fotosEliminar = db.FOTO.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) idsEliminarList.Contains(x.IdFoto))

If fotosEliminar IsNot Nothing Then
   noticiaSelec.FOTO.Remove(fotosEliminar)
End If
```

---

Si se requiere eliminar varios registros entonces hay que iterar por cada uno

```
Dim fotosEliminar = db.FOTO.Where(Function(x) idsEliminarList.Contains(x.IdFoto))

For Each item In fotosEliminar    
   noticiaSelec.FOTO.Remove(item) 
Next

db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Esto solo elimina un registro, lo que @Danilo necesita es eliminar multiples registros

Comment: Exacto @CarlosMuñoz

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se desea eliminar varios items al mismo tiempo, se utiliza RemoveAll()

Cambia el siguiente código:

```
Dim fotosEliminar = db.FOTO.Where(Function(x) idsEliminarList.Contains(x.IdFoto))        
noticiaSelec.FOTO.Remove(fotosEliminar) ‘ Aquí es donde se cae
```

Por algo asi:

```
Dim fotosEliminar = db.FOTO.RemoveAll(Function(x) idsEliminarList.Contains(x.IdFoto))
```

Comment: El RemoveAll no lo reconoce, por se aplica cuando es una lista

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo parecido http://forums.asp.net/t/1469970.aspx?Convert+C+to+VB+LINQ+RemoveAll+ Espero te sea de utilidad.